# Seaborn axvspan alterating x-axis

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create some scatter plots, with seaborn with a specific area of each plot highlighted in red. However when I add the code for axvspan, it changes the x-axis. This is how the plots look prior to axvspan being applied.

[image]

When i apply the line for axvpsan:

```
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(5,10))

ax0.axvspan("0.4", "0.8", color='red', alpha=0.3, label ='Problem Area')
sns.scatterplot(x='Values_1', y='Values_2', data=df3, color='green', ax=ax0)
sns.scatterplot(x='Values_3', y='Values_4', data=df3, color='green', ax=ax1)
plt.show()
```

It sends up looking like this:

[image]

Ultimately, the red section needs to only cover the data between 0.4 and 0.7, but by altering the x-axis it ends up covering all of it.

Any advice?

Comment: Could you please add `df3` in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unexpected behavior is resulting from passing the `xmin` and `xmax` arguments to [`matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html) as `str` and not as `float`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

# generate data
rng = np.random.default_rng(12)
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Values_2": rng.random(100), "Values_1": np.linspace(0., 0.6, 100)})

fig, ax0 = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6, 4))
ax0.axvspan(0.4, 0.8, color='red', alpha=0.3, label ='Problem Area')

sns.scatterplot(x='Values_1', y='Values_2', data=df3, color='green', ax=ax0)
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]